# videoJs player does not initialise properly after a different player has finished initialising

Tags: javascript, video.js

I have a problem where I need to find the duration of the media before initialising my videoJs player.

To do this, I have been trying to get the duration by loading a hidden player with the media in getting the duration, then setting options based on that duration to use in the second player.

I have found though that if I do this, then the second player will not initialise properly.

In my example I have two players identicle both with the same options.  The only difference being is that one initialises 1 second after the first one.

```
var videoJsOptions = {
  controlBar: {
    progressControl: false,
    remainingTimeDisplay: false,
    durationDisplay: false,
    currentTimeDisplay: false,
    timeDivider: false,
  },
};

var player = videojs('my-video', videoJsOptions);
player.src('http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4');
player.muted(true);
player.play();

window.setTimeout(() => {
  var player2 = videojs('my-video-1', videoJsOptions);
  player2.src('http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4');
  player2.muted(true);
  player2.play();
}, 1000);
```

You can see from the screenshot, that the first generates correctly, with the control scroll bar hidden, whereas the second one ignores these settings and displays the bar incorrectly.

[image]

Can anyone help me here, I am happy to destroy the first video Js player but disposing does not seem to fix the issue.

The videos are not loading for some reason on here, but you can still see the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/3kuqb6cL/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their docs, it says:

> By default, when your web page finishes loading, Video.js will scan for media elements that have the data-setup attribute. The data-setup attribute is used to pass options to Video.js.

So, if you just remove the `data-setup` attribute, it will use the options you pass.  Otherwise, it won't.  I'm guessing it just happened to work on the first one due to some race condition - you happened to set it up before the auto setup got to it.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    controls
  ></video>

  <video
    id="my-video-1"
    class="video-js"
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    controls
  ></video>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video.js"></script>

  <script>
    var videoJsOptions = {
      controlBar: {
        progressControl: false,
        remainingTimeDisplay: false,
        durationDisplay: false,
        currentTimeDisplay: false,
        timeDivider: false,
      },
    };

    var player = videojs('#my-video', videoJsOptions);
    player.src('http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4');
    player.muted(true);
    player.play();

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      var player2 = videojs('#my-video-1', videoJsOptions);
      player2.src('http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4');
      player2.muted(true);
      player2.play();
    }, 1000);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i have wasted about 4 hours banging my head against the wall on this today. Removing that one line has fixed it all!